# How to Search data from api list in flutter searchable dropdown list

Tags: flutter

i m in a situation where i have to implement country city state dropdown list somehow i manage things with normal flutter dropdown button and that's work ,but the issue is i can't search  data in that dropdown button so user have to scroll and find there country or city which is a very bad user experience , so i found this package https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown whic is working but i m not sure how to implement that search in my code here is my code
data from fututre

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:foodfromforeign1/models/country.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';

void main() => runApp( MyApp());



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme:  ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home:  MyHomePage(title: 'Users'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() =>  _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/fff/api/allcountries/";
 List data = List(); //line
Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      data = resBody.;
    });

    return "Sucess";
  }

    @override
  void initState() {
    this.getSWData();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        title:  Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
        child:Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           TypeAheadField<data>(
      onSuggestionSelected: (data) => print('selected: ${data.name} ${data.id}'),
      suggestionsCallback: (s) => data.where((c) => c.name.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())),
      itemBuilder: (ctx, data) => Text(data.name, textScaleFactor: 2,),
    )
         ],

        ),  




      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: *"so i m open for suggestion if there is any better solution for this type of work"* - [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) for example?

Comment: is that will return id of the country to me to pass to next function

Comment: my above code working now when i make the value string,,,,but then is their any way to still get the id as i m assigning the value to name then it working but i need to get id as well

Comment: `TypeAheadField<T>` widget can use any data model - here `T` can be your custom class storing name and id

Comment: suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
            return CitiesService.getSuggestions(pattern);
          },    what is this is it list of data? and what is this pattren for flutter is so confusion

Comment: how to implement my data with as you can see my future function above in my code

Comment: Well the example you provided that worked, but i have change my code removed class and fetch data from api,but when i pass TypeAheadField<data> data to this function it says  The name 'data' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named    can you have a look please

Answer (score -1):

Another option here aside from using plugins is with the use of the [Autocomplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) widget. This should inflate an autocomplete list over other widgets. If you're using a `List<Object>` from an API response, you can map the keywords that you need to filter from to a `List<String>` to be used in the Autocomplete widget. The index can be used as a reference on the `List<Object>` to fetch the Object.

```dart
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Orange'];

_autoCompleteTextField() {
  return Autocomplete(
    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
      if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
        return const Iterable<String>.empty();
      }
      return fruits.where((String option) {
        return option
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
    onSelected: (String selection) {
      debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
    },
  );
}
```

[image: Demo]